# Массив как возвращаемое значение функции

Tags: c

Мне нужно создать функцию, которая возвращает массив, но при этом не пользоваться динамической памятью и глобальными переменными. Например: функция принимает массив как параметр, переписывает из него все отрицательные числа в новый массив и возвращает указатель на этот массив.

```
int* NewLine(int* sr, int* nr)
{
    int nr[20]; // выделяем память на новый массив
    int* p = nr;
    ...
    return nr;
}
```

- Первый параметр - массив, в котором будем искать отрицательные числа.
- Второй - адрес, по которому в масив записываем найденые елементы.

Но какие фактические параметры мне нужно передавать при вызове функции? Первый - собственно сам анализируемый массив, а какой второй?

Comment: Для небольших массивов можно завернуть массив в структуру и вернуть ее (структуры по правилам языка Си можно присваивать (копировать)). Что-то вроде `struct arr { int a[20];};  ... struct arr f(int *sr) {struct arr res; ... res.a[i] = sr[j];...  return res;} ... main () { int x[20] = {....}; struct arr p = f(x); ...}` / Хорошей идеей будет хранить в такой структуре вместе с массивом его размер и актуальное количество элементов